# How to create a Logs with React + Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, logging

I need create info logs (files). I'm using the winston for that.

I have a doubt with create an Restfull endpoint on my react application.

On my server.js I created this method:

```
app.get('/api/logger', (req, res) => {
  logger.log('info', `Client: inside`);
  return res.send('OK');
});
```

But ever when I try access (or send to) this route, the browser returns me 404

This is my method created on my component:

```
callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/logger');
    console.log(response);
  };
```

Comment: Do you serve your React app from your Node.js server? Or is it served from another server?

Comment: both running in same port 8081 (local)